# Modifying wordpress htaccess to forward certain urls to subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

For whatever reason or another I haven't been able to ascertain, my company has decided to go with wordpress for one of their websites. They asked me to build an affiliate application on the same domain, which I did. Everything works great with the exception of this dilemma:

wordpress is installed in the root directory. All pages, videos, sales, etc are made from within wordpress pages.

The affiliate application is in a subdirectory /aff/ and affiliates' pages are found at mydomain.com/aff/index.php?aff=affiliateusername

Affiliates (and their leads) should be able to load their pages simply by typing in www.mydomain.com/affiliateusername but I am struggling to understand how to translate wordpress htaccess rules to do this.

Obviously the best order in which to have this work is for wordpress to first determine if there are any blogs/posts/pages that match the url term FIRST, and if none is found, then to redirect all else to www.mydomain.com/aff/index.php?aff=whatever

Here's what I was finally able to come up with that works for the index page and for the affiliate pages, but does not correctly load any wordpress pages other than index.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(images|wp-admin|wp-content|wp-includes|go|compliance\.html)($|/) - [L]
#RewriteRule ^([^/].*)$ /aff/index.php?aff=$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

You can tell I've attempted to exclude certain directories from the rewrite but have not been successful. I've read other advice via Googling, to put the redirect rules ahead of the wordpress block, but there are few issues. When I put this line ahead of the # BEGIN WordPress line, I get an endless redirect loop which keeps going to /aff/index.php?aff=aff/index.php?... etc (this is the same line I use for the same affiliate application on a different, wordpress-free, domain)

```
#RewriteRule ^([^/].*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/aff/index.php?aff=$1 [L]
```

I feel like I'm missing something terribly obvious. Should I just be setting up wordpress to redirect all 404's to /aff/index.php?aff=originalrequest? How would I go about doing that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `RewriteRule`s incorrectly in place of `RewriteCond`s. Adding them in between the WordPress rules is surely breaking your blog as well. Change your `.htaccess` code to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /aff/index.php?aff=$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you want the URL to stay `mydomain.com/affiliate` remove the `[R]` and use only `[QSA,L]`.

---

I've updated the rules above to show how to exclude a path from affiliate redirection. The following

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog\b
```

excludes all URLs pointing to `/blog` or its sub-directories `/blog/sub/dirs` from redirection.

---

If there are root-level `.php` pages present (even if they are few) the exclusion can more easily be handled by changing the rule to

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /aff/index.php?aff=$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

assuming that a `.` and a `/` can never be present in an affiliate name.

Comment: First of all - Thank you very much. This makes sense to put it ahead of the index.php rewrite rule. At first blush this works perfectly and loads the index page as well as the affiliate pages correctly. However, the blog pages are redirecting to the affiliate page as well. I attempted to exclude the pages from this rewrite rule in the way that I know how, which I don't think works because of the unique way in which wordpress utilizes the URL. I'd be OK with excluding each and every blog page URL from the affiliate redirect, but how would I accomplish this?

Comment: @user1867350 could you tell what your blog page urls are like? Currently my rule assumes that `mydomain.com/anything-without-slash` is an affiliate.

Comment: Yes, well - initially the user visits the index.php and opts in, after which they are taken through a series of several upsell/downsell combination pages, all in wordpress. So there are 7 wordpress pages to exclude, such as www.mydomain.com/page-to-exclude1.php, www.mydomain.com/page-to-exclude2.php etc. There aren't very many, but there are a few.

Comment: @user1867350, if `.` can never be present in an affiliate name, this can more easily be handled by matching the `RewriteRule` on `[^/.]+`. Check update.

Comment: Works perfectly - and there will never be any characters other than alphanumerical in the affiliate name. Let me see if I understand the principles involved. RewriteCond is where one defines a term to watch for and what needs to be done with it. RewriteRule is what to do with pages if nothing has yet matched any of the prior conditions. This bit here: ^([^/]+)$ means including everything prior to the term, and excluding another forward slash, then whatever that term is will be handled in the next statement. ^([^/.]+)$ is the same thing but excluding another forward slash and a period.

Comment: I'm afraid it's a bit more complex than that. But, this [introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html) would get you up to speed in no time.

Comment: I'll study it. Thanks again for taking the time to put me on the right track.